# Displaying formula fields on VF Page

Tags: visualforce, formula-field

[image]I have a `Custom Object` called `Revenue_Reports__c`. On this object I have a formula field called `Revenue_by_Year__c`. The formula field is as follows:

```
HYPERLINK("/00O130000097aES?pv3=" & CASESAFEID($User.Id), "Rev Report")
```

How can I display this formula field as a hyperlink on my `Visualforce Page`?

```
<apex:pageblockSection title="My Orders for Today" collapsible="false">
<apex:outputLink value="https://cs28.salesforce.com/00O13000008UrTd">Orders for Today
<apex:outputField value="{!Revenue_Reports__c.Revenue_by_Year__c}"/>
</apex:outputLink>
</apex:pageblockSection>
```

Comment: After reading your back-and-forth with Adrian... perhaps we should take it back to basics? What if you remove the `<apex:outputField>` from inside the outputLink, and just replace it with words like `Test Link`? Does the link show up then?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [`<apex:outputField>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputField.htm) tag:

```
<apex:page standardController="MyObject__c">
    <apex:outputField value="{!MyObject__c.LinkFormula__c}" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I tried and for some reason it doesn't work. I am adding the code in the question. Can you check what am i missing.

Comment: You don't need the `<apex:outputLink>` tag at all.

Comment: When I just try <apex:outputField value="{!Revenue_Reports__c.Revenue_by_Year__c}"/> nothing gets displayed on vfpage. Any idea if this could be other reason

Comment: Do you actually have view permission on that field as the running user?

Comment: Poor selection of words. I can actually see the field but I cannot see it in hyperlink format. if you actually see the formula field I am trying to display it as hyperlink

Comment: I repeat, you should not be using the `<apex:outputLink>` tag *at all*. If you change your markup to remove that and add a screenshot, it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50043/discussion-between-sfdclearner-and-adrian-larson).

Comment: I added the screen shot. Revenue by Year is my formula field and I want the formula field to be shown as a hyperlink and I have not used any output link tags

Comment: The chat does't load for some reason. All i want to do is display the formula field on vf page as hyperlink.

Comment: You almost certainly do not have Read permission on that field. Check Field Level Security and make sure you can actually read it.